# get list of static libraries in c/cpp from .so/.o files

Tags: c++, c, linux, binary, linker

I've been trying to get **static and dynamic dependencies** from files. I have the source code and unstipped bin files,
To get all of the dynamic dependencies I used this line and its worked

```
readelf -d $1 | grep "NEEDED\|RPATH" | perl  -pe 's/.*\[(.*)\]/$1/
```

My problem is with the static libraries, when I'm using the command:

`nm path/to/so`

I'm getting the names of the functions and not the files.
Is there any way to see the static dependencies for each binary file?

Comment: To my little knowledge the answer is: no. A static librarie is just an archive of object files. Linking a static library is the same as linking your different object files.

Comment: maybe found some way, my script right now is :                                                                                
"readelf -d $1 | grep "NEEDED\|RPATH" | perl  -pe 's/.*\[(.*)\]/$1/'|sort -u | tee DynamicDep_$2\.txt " for dynamic and 
   " strings -a $1 | grep -E '\.h' | sort -u | sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" | tee StaticDep_$2\.txt" for static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic libraries (.so) cannot have "static dependencies" as they are already linked.

Object files (.o) and static libraries (.a) define symbols that they export (to be used by others) and symbols they themselves use.

You can list the symbols of object files using the `nm` command. For example:

```
$ nm lukas.o
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 U __dso_handle
0000000000000000 V DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
00000000000003a8 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z15double_from_strRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
00000000000001d5 T main
                 U __stack_chk_fail
                 U _Unwind_Resume
```

The `U` keyword marks the symbols that are undefined, that is, **the static dependencies** of the object file.